# Shifted linear gradient in flexbox on wider screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Dunno why am I getting shifted linear gradient at bottom of the first rectangle when width of viewport is at least 1000px.

[image]

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcf33qrx/2/)**

**gradient:**

```
.hero:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 65%, rgb(93, 240, 255) 120%);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'shifted linear gradient'? That looks exactly the same at all sizes

Comment: [Here it is](http://i.imgur.com/ocMVQjD.png), also I mentioned that may be because of this reason, additional space is adding from the right side

Comment: Let me know if this work: `.hero:first-child { flex-basis: calc(66.6% - 10px); }`

Comment: @LGSon, yeah it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the linear gradient or anything like that, the width of the top two elements is different to the width of the bottom three (`520 + 255 = 775` *vs* `255 + 255 + 255 = 765`). And then you are using `calc` with a % value, so the actual (px) difference changes depending on screen size